# Serialisation with inheritance in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Given a .proto that looks like this:

```
message Base {
    string Dummy = 1
}

message Derived {
    Base Super = 1
    string Parp = 2 
}
```

... And some C# something like:

```
public class Base {
    public string Dummy;
}

public class Derived : Base {
    public string Parp
}
```

How would one go about customising the serialisation in protobuf-net to be able to do this? Initially I started looking at using a TypeModel and calling AddSubType for the Base MetaType, but then it seems it creates type definitions for Base with optional fields of all the derived classes (ie the other way around vs what I require)

I thought I might be able to walk the hierarchy myself but looking at TypeModel, it seems to support supplying the type to Deserialise but it uses value.GetType() during serialisation. Even then it wasn't entirely clear how I might do this. Is my only option to use ProtoWriter to write every field by hand? This is what I am currently attempting, but I hoped there was an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that protobuf itself does not support inheritance. There is no "official" layout for this. Protobuf-net will not support serialization the way you desire: the choice of sub-type encapsulation (rather than base-type encapsulation) was made to fix several issues, including:

- satisfying the Liskov substitution principle
- working correctly when the serialized type was not known/expected by the caller
- basically, working at all (for anything other than the simplest example where both ends know in advance exactly which sub-type they are getting, which largely defeats the point of polymorphism)

However, you could map the DTO manually, basically so your DTO layer doesn't use inheritance at all.

Comment: Thanks Marc... I appreciate it doesn't support it, but using this notion of super pointers (and yes, I know my message type in advance), can I roll my own deserialisation with the ProtoReader/Writer?

Comment: @chrism that depends on how much of it you are happy to write yourself.  The ProtoReader/ProtoWriter API provides full access to processing the wire format, but you would have to handle all the field-level handling - there isn't an IProtoSerializable, for example, to allow control to just one type.

Comment: Any other advice? Having a separate set of DTOs I map to seems like I would be doing lots of allocations just to copy data into objects for serialisation/deserialisation

Comment: @chrism "a lot" is subjective and depends on the scenario; additionally, as short-lived objects they could very-well be collected from gen-0. What I'm saying is: we can't say whether "a lot" is "too much" without more context (throughput, etc). But: how many types are involved in your model (just trying to assess how much code would be involved in a reader/writer approach). Finally, what is the requirement for the specific layout? If it is to match another non-protobuf-net layout, then I would say: don't use inheritance: use encapsulation that matches your desired wire layout.

Comment: At peek, 1000's a second. The layout is this way because of exactly that, its integrating into an already existing code base where the message layout uses super pointers. The desire for inheritance is so that an XYZRequest would derive from a Request in C# for example, but on the wire the type would have a Super field of type Request

Comment: I have an idea; can I test it later and get back to you?

Comment: @chrism I tried my idea - it wasn't successful. Unless I invest some time adding features, I don't have anything better at the current time.